# Annual percent rate: need advice

Tags: javascript, math

I have this code:

```
Round((Math.pow( (( 1 + (comission / initial))), ( 1 / (days / 365))) - 1) * 100, 2)
```

It works fine if I take $1000 for 60 days and return $1000+comission in one payment after 60 days.

But I want to return it in 2 or 3 or more payments per 60 day period.

I can't just divide 'APR/number of payments' because APR must increase not decrease.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with [tag:mathematica] AFAICS. Or jQuery, for that matter.

Comment: What are your assumptions? Are you comfortable with algebra? If it's a fixed "comission", why not just divide the result by 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1):

The APR depends on the compounding frequency, and could be the sum of an infinite series when compounding continuously.

The periodic and continuous formulas are explained pretty well at the page [Continuously Compunded Interest Formula and Calculator](http://www.moneychimp.com/articles/finworks/continuous_compounding.htm) (and has a calculator to demonstate!) on the ["moneychimp"](http://moneychimp.com) web site.

Basically, for periodic compounding the Future Value at period *n* is ...

FV<sub>n</sub> = P(1 + r/n)<sup>Yn</sup>

for Principal `P` compunded `n` times per year after `Y` years.

You can determine the APR by calculating the future value of a fixed amount `X` after one year, and finding the resulting interest rate, e.g.

APR = ((FV - P) / P) * 100

For example, given a Principal of 10,000 at 5% (0.05) compounded monthly (12 periods / year) you get

10,000 * (( 1 + 0.05/12 )^12) = 10,511.62

(10,511.62 - 10,000) / 10,000 = 0.051162 ... * 100 = 5.1152 (or 5.12) percent APR

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already have script with you example. If you can comment something about this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#European_Union would be nice because I need this type of APR.